# Flutter Card widget onTap() to open Slidable

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, slider

I have a `Slidable` widget with a `Card` child and was wondering is it possible for me to open the `Slidable` when I tapped on the `Card`? I have tried using `SlidableController` but this class seems buggy as it keeps returning null for me. Besides, I also tried using the `groupTag` property in `Slidable` but it also not working on my project. The below is the sample code and hoping if anyone could help:

```
Slidable(
  endActionPane: ActionPane(motion: const DrawerMotion(), children: [
    Expanded(
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: smallCircularRadius,
                    bottomRight: smallCircularRadius),
                gradient: customColors.progressBarGradient),
            child: ContactOptions(
                contact: data.getContact(), email: data.email)))
  ]),
  child: CustomCard(
      onTap: () {
        Slidable.of(context)!.openEndActionPane();
      },
      child: ListTile(
          dense: true,
          leading: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle, size: 50),
          title:
              Text('KOO KIAN KEAT'),
          subtitle: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text('----',
                    style: customTextStyles.bodySmall)
              ]))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace your child to below code

```
Slidable(
     endActionPane: ActionPane(motion: const DrawerMotion(), 
     children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: smallCircularRadius,
                    bottomRight: smallCircularRadius),
                gradient: customColors.progressBarGradient),
            child: ContactOptions(
                contact: data.getContact(), email: data.email)))
  ]),
  child: CardWidget()
) 


 class CardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    const CardWidget({
        Key? key,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
  final Color color;
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Slidable.of(context)!.openEndActionPane();
      },
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        elevation: 0,
        child: ListTile(
          onTap: () {
            Slidable.of(context)!.openEndActionPane();
          },
          leading: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle, size: 50),
          title: Text('KOO KIAN KEAT'),
          subtitle: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [Text('----')],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I know which version / which library you used to use the class ```SlidableState```?

Comment: @Leong Please check above answer, i have edited some code

Comment: the ```Slidable.of(context)!.openEndActionPane()``` will give me "Null check used on a null value"...

Comment: Use above code for your child widget and make this child into particular stateless widget

Comment: I am using it in my child widget and it is a stateless widget

Comment: Can you provide me snapshot for your code, so i can help you more in your issue

Comment: I already updated my code in the question

Comment: instead of your code, please use `CardWidget` in child

Comment: the ```CustomCard``` in my code is basically the same thing as your ```CardWidget``` (```Card``` wrapped with ```GestureDetector```)

Comment: Please check above answer, i have edited some code

Comment: as long as I called the line ```Slidable.of(context)!.openEndActionPane();``` it will prompt me "Null check used on a null value". I think is because the ```Slidable.of(context)``` keeps returning me null value...

Comment: Replace above code into your code

Comment: Can I know what is the problem on my code?

Answer (score 1):

Following the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable):

You can do something like

```
final controller = SlidableController();

// Open the actions
void _handleOpen() {
  controller.openEndActionPane();
  // OR
  //controller.openStartActionPane();
}

// ...

child: Slidable(
    controller: controller,
    endActionPane: ActionPane(
      motion: const DrawerMotion(),
      ...
))
```

So, put your card inside a Inkwell widget

```
child: InkWell(
  onTap: _handleOpen,
  child: const Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
    elevation: 0,
    child: ListTile(
      dense: true,
      leading: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle, size: 50),
      title: Text('KOO KIAN KEAT'),
      subtitle: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [Text('----')],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I tried the first method mentioned, but I cant create the ```SlidableController``` in my project

Comment: @Leong "cant create the SlidableController" What error you get?

Comment: "1 positional argument expected by ```SlidableController.new```, but 0 found. Try adding the missing argument."

Comment: i tried this way: ```late SlidableController controller = SlidableController(this);```, then I managed to create the controller but when I apply the ```controller!.openEndActionPane()```, it always returns me a null value

Comment: did you do a hot reaload after the create the late variable?